# lsqcurvefit vs fmincon in matlab to estimate parameters

Tags: matlab, least-squares, estimation

I have fitted some data to a nonlinear ODE system to estimate the ODE model parameters. I did it using `lsqcurvefit` but now  for a different reason want to try it using `fmincon` (as now I want to fit two data sets to the same model simultaneously).

First, I tried fitting the same data that I used with `lsqcurvefit` and just changing the code only to include `fmincon`.
 My question is `fmincon` doesn't give a good fit even I use the `lsqcurvefit` estimations as inital guesses.
Since I am minimising the objective function as

```
sum((fitted-data)^2)
```

which is equivalent to `lsqcurvefit` why don't I get a good fit in `fmincon`?

This is the matlab code,

```
lb=[0,0.001,0,0,0,0,0];
ub=[inf,inf,1,1,1,100,100];
x=[thours,data];

[fit,fval]=fmincon(@(parameters)ssq(parameters,x),initial,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)

function SSE=ssq(parameters,x)
    time=x(:,1);
    data=x(:,2);


    fitted=model(parameters,time);
    error1=fitted(:,1)-data;
    SSE=sum(error1.^2);


end

function [output]= model(parameters,thours) 
%ODE model code
```

Comment: The first thing I'd check is that `fitted(:,1)` is a column vector and not just the first element of a row vector.  But in general you should expect the functions to give different results as they use different algorithms, are likely to be calculating the cost in a slightly different way, and `fmincon` needs to (in general) deal with constraints that lsqcurvefit doesn't.  Have a look at [Choosing the Algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-the-algorithm.html) to see a complete list of the algorithms used.